# How to rotate a sprite around a fixed point so it follows cursor

Tags: html5-canvas, pixi.js

I'm developing a small minigolf game, where the user can shoot moving the cursor around to set an angle, and the force applied will be the length of an arrow (less force when the cursor is closer to the ball). You can check exactly how it works here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQmw4.jpg

I have figured out how to rotate the arrow sprite to follow the cursor but I don't know yet how to make it move around the ball, right now it's just rotating in its anchor, in this case the head of the arrow.

I'm using Panda.js (a Pixi.js based framework) to develop the game, but its API is similar to the native Canvas functions. I don't need an exact implementation (that's why I'm not posting any code), but I would like to get some ideas about how to rotate the sprite around a point in a given radius. In this case, the point would be the center of the ball, and the radius will be the ball radius. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You set the point of rotation with `ctx.translate` or `ctx.setTransform` then apply the rotation with `ctx.rotate(ang);` Then draw the image offset so that the point of rotation is at (0,0). Ie if you want the point of rotation to be at image coordinates (100,50) then render at `ctx.drawImage(image,-100,-50);`

To get the angle from a point to the mouse use `Math.atan2`

```js
requestAnimationFrame(update);

// draws rotated image at x,y.
// cx, cy is the image coords you want it to rotate around
function drawSprite(image, x, y, cx, cy, rotate) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
  ctx.rotate(rotate);
  ctx.drawImage(image, -cx, -cy);
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // restore defaults
}

// function gets the direction from point to mouse and draws an image 
// rotated to point at the mouse
function rotateAroundPoint(x, y, mouse) {
  const dx = mouse.x - x;
  const dy = mouse.y - y;
  const dir = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  drawSprite(arrow, x, y, 144, 64, dir);
}

// Main animation loop.
function update(timer) {
  globalTime = timer;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  strokeCircle(150, 75, 10);
  rotateAroundPoint(150, 75, mouse);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


//=====================================================
// All the rest is unrelated to the answer.

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse = {  x: 0, y: 0, button: false };
["down", "up", "move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
function mouseEvents(e) {
  mouse.bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  mouse.x = e.pageX - mouse.bounds.left - scrollX;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - mouse.bounds.top - scrollY;
  mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
const CImage = (w = 128, h = w) => (c = document.createElement("canvas"), c.width = w, c.height = h, c);
const CImageCtx = (w = 128, h = w) => (c = CImage(w, h), c.ctx = c.getContext("2d"), c);
const drawPath = (ctx, p) => {var i = 0;while (i < p.length) {ctx.lineTo(p[i++], p[i++])}};
const strokeCircle = (l,y=ctx,r=ctx,c=ctx) =>{if(l.p1){c=y; r=leng(l);y=l.p1.y;l=l.p1.x }else if(l.x){c=r;r=y;y=l.y;l=l.x}c.beginPath(); c.arc(l,y,r,0,Math.PI*2); c.stroke()};
const aW = 10;
const aH = 20;
const ind = 5;
const arrow = CImageCtx();
arrow.ctx.beginPath();
drawPath(arrow.ctx, [
  ind, 64 - aW,
  128 - ind - aH, 64 - aW,
  128 - ind - aH, 64 - aH,
  128 - ind, 64,
  128 - ind - aH, 64 + aH,
  128 - ind - aH, 64 + aW,
  ind, 64 + aW,
]);
arrow.ctx.fillStyle = "red";
arrow.ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2; // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var globalTime;
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```